# transpose rowname of Group ID to column names without aggregation in R

Tags: r

I have attach the photo that describe transpose issue from table 1 to table 2.
May I seek your solution for this ?

[image: Tranpose the table]

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `melt/dcast` from `data.table`.  In the devel version, there is `rowid` to create a sequence column by group.

```
library(data.table)#1.9.7+
dcast(melt(setDT(table1), id.var = 'ID', variable.name = "V"),
               V + rowid(ID)~ID, value.var = "value")[, ID := NULL][]
```

If we are using versions 1.9.6 or below,

```
dcast(melt(setDT(table), id.var = "ID", variable.name = "V")[,
   rn := 1:.N, by = ID], V + rn ~ID, value.var = "value")[, ID := NULL][]
```

#### data

```
table1 <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("GroupA", "GroupB"), c(7, 5)), 
       V1 = c(2, 2, 4, 3, 1,6, 7, 8, 11, 3, 1, 6),
       V2 = c(2, 4, 2, 7, 1, 8, 5, 9, 12, 21, 4, 6))
```

Comment: thanks but it shows some error message :Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "rowid"    ?

Comment: @user7091378  It is in the devel version of data.table 1.9.7.  Updated with another option from 1.9.6